# Performance of transition CSS on *:link,*:visited,*:hover,*:active,*:focus

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-transitions

I am looking at the following stylesheet snippet:

```
*:link,*:visited,*:hover,*:active,*:focus {
    transition: color .25s linear, background-color .25s linear, border-color .25s linear;
}
```

And wonder what the performance impact is, especially on mobile devices?
Wouldn't it be better to be more specific like ".ClassName:hover", or is performance difference no issue?
Please your advice?

Comment: Transitions are defined on a per-element basis. Your selector could easily be simplified into `*` and the transitions you assign would kick in when any of those pseudo-classes apply, as long as you define some change in the respective properties for those states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I want to know why you want to use that, do you want that each and every element on your page should be assigned `transition` for  color, `border-color` on `:hover`, `:active` state....? Because this will be applied to all the elements, when `hovered`, `focused`, where as `link` and `visited` will be applied to `a` tags.

If you want to apply the above styles to the link, you should be using

```
a:link, a:visited ...
```

Also, when you are using `*`, it is going to be an expensive selector for your webpage. So use it only if required.

[image]

<sup>1. [Good Read For Selector Performance](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/06/18/simplifying-css-selectors/)</sup>
<sup>2. [Testing Page Efficiency](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/?csw=1)</sup>

---

Performance will surely be degraded, using specific(not over specific) selectors will be a much better option compared to `*`, though I still feel the selector you will be using is not what you need, you must be targeting `a` element and not ALL elements.

Comment: I encountered it in a delivered piece of work and was wandering the same... Thanks ..

Comment: @edbras nah, if you are using something like `* {margin: 0; padding: 0; outline: 0;}` is ok, but using pseudo classes with `*` is not used.

Answer (score 1):

Any use of the * selector causes the rendering to take significantly longer, as every element on the page will match an extra item, one for which the selector is non-specific enough as to need more processing power to find.  It increases parsing time of the CSS file, and the delay before rendering of the page itself.  Browsers have ways of making up for code, to an extent, but it's still going to be a pain, even on the better browsers.

In your case, the styles you are selecting involve the pseudo classes hover, active, etc.  These are based on events, so not only are you reading through the entire document more than necessary, you are essentially binding events to them, which will need to be stored in memory.

Add to that that the style itself is a transition, and there's extra processing power needed when those events are called.

Also, applying the transition to the pseudo class means that it actually wouldn't even work, because the transition wouldn't be applied until the background color had already changed, except for a[href] items, which would already have it matched from the *:link selector.

This code is much less expensive, and would achieve what it seems you want to do:

```
a[href] {
        transition: color .25s linear, background-color .25s linear, border-color .25s linear;

}

a[href]:hover, a[href]:active, a[href]:focus {
    background-color: /* New colour */
    border-color: /* New colour */
    color: /* New colour */
}
```

Even then, I'm reasonably sure that you probably don't need the focus, and maybe active pseudoclasses.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the event listener binding, clear.